# json, how do check for the key?

Tags: javascript, json

I am reusing a function in my javascript for two places.

Within this method I make a call and retrieve a json object (data)

```
data[0].fields['status']
```

In one of the cases I know that the key 'status' won't be there and I need to use a hardcoded value, but since the code is shared for both cases, I need to capture this case.

Is there a get method to check safely for the key and if it doesn't exist I would use the hardcoded value?

```
data[0].fields.get('status') ?
```

Or is there is a better way?

Comment: You need to know that some of the methods that will be posted here are not accepted by some *strict* ECMAScript programmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check whether a property is existent on an object:

```
if ('status' in data[0].fields) …
```

You also could use a simple boolean evaluation if your potential value is truthy, because the `undefined` evaluates to false. You can use that even in a [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation):

```
return data[0].fields.status || defaultstate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Commonly:

```
var status = data[0].fields['status'] || "default";
```

As pointed out, this may produce an undesired behavior for *falsy* values.

Also, alternatively to the `in` operator, you can make use of [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method.

Comment: While this is great shorthand for many controlled cases, you should point out that if `data[0].fields['status']` is **set, but falsy** it will fail to "default" which is likely not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( typeof data[0].fields['status'] === 'undefined' ) data[0].fields['status'] = 'hardcoded value';
// your code goes on here
```

Comment: This does not work it the value itself is `undefined` - you'd better should use `in` (which is also shorter)